# How to access a relational table in rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-console

How do I access the relational table `UserRole` of the database in the rails console?

Schema:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20140709163149) do
  create_table "users", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "stuff"
    ...
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  create_table "roles", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "label"
    ...
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  create_table "user_roles", force: true do |t|
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.integer  "role_id"
    ...
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  add_index "user_roles", ["role_id"], name: "index_user_roles_on_role_id"
  add_index "user_roles", ["user_id"], name: "index_user_roles_on_user_id"
```

In the rails console, I can do `User.all()` and get all the users, and I can do `Role.all()`, but how do I access the relationship table `user_role`? Ultimately so I can seed the database.

If I try `UserRole.all()`, I get the following:

```
NameError: uninitialized constant UserRole
    from (irb):7
    from /Users/dejanew/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:90:in `start'
    from /Users/dejanew/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
    from /Users/dejanew/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:69:in `console'
    from /Users/dejanew/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:40:in `run_command!'
    from /Users/dejanew/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/dejanew/Dropbox/dev/SDF/bin/rails:8:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/dejanew/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Users/dejanew/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from -e:1:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully this is a simple solution.

Your `app/models` directory should have `user.rb`, `user_role.rb`, and `role.rb`.

Where `user_role.rb` looks something like this:

`class UserRole < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :role
end`

Also note, that the `type` field for `Role` may trigger [single table inheritance](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#label-Single+table+inheritance).

Comment: Thanks for the note about single table inheritance!,  fixed that in a migration

Comment: Ah!,   the `scaffold` wasn't used for this, hence why it didn't create it.  I truly hate using shortcuts until you fully understand a framework!

Answer (score 1):

You need to define a model called `UserRole` in `app/models/user_role.rb`.

When you use `User.all()` and `Roll.all()`, you're accessing classes defined (presumably) in `app/models/user.rb` and `app/models/role.rb` respectively. You are *not* directly accessing the tables through some syntactic sugar available in the Rails console, you're simply using plain old classes defined by your application's code. You need to do the same for `UserRole`.

Answer (score 1):

User and Role are not database tables. They're models, which is a word used in Rails to mean Ruby classes that inherit from ActiveRecord::Base.

You defined the User model when you typed (or generated with `rails generate`) `class User < ActiveRecord::Base ... end` in `/app/models/user.rb`. Rails automatically hooks the User and Role models up to the `users` and `roles` tables, but that's (for our purposes) coincidental. User and Role exist because there are classes with those names defined in `/app/models`, not because there are database tables called `users` and `roles`.

If you want to be have a model called `UserRole`, you'll have to define it. You'll do that by creating (or generating) `/users/models/user_role.rb` and putting `class UserRole < ActiveRecord::Base ... end` in it.